# AngularJS: Having a directive which should act like a native select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive which should act like a native select. That means if I have set the required attribute, it should be invalid if nothing was selected.

So far I have the following coffeescript:

```
'use strict'

angular.module('myApp').directive 'countrySelect', (iso3166) ->
  restrict: 'EA'
  template: '<select><option ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country.iso2}}">{{country.name}}</option></select>'
  replace: true
  scope:
    model: '=ngModel'
  link: ($scope) ->
    $scope.countries = iso3166.countries
```

This generates a list of all countries which is then used as followed: `<country-select ng-model="masterData.country" required></country-select>`

Now I wonder how to set the directive to be invalid.

Comment: You can set the required attribute in the directive template just like you would normally. `<select required><option ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country.iso2}}">{{country.name}}</option></select>`

You should set an ng-model for the select so that you can use the input in the directive or controller.

Comment: try this `<select required ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="c.iso2 as c.name for c in countries"></select>` That will generate a list of options for you